# Removing any characters after a comma in a column python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a column in a df like so:

```
city

Rockford, IL    
St. Petersburg  
Oklahoma City   
Memphis 
Indianapolis
Naples, FL
```

I want to know how to remove the comma and following characters from elements in the column that have it. so new one like this:

```
  city
Rockford    
St. Petersburg  
Oklahoma City   
Memphis 
Indianapolis
Naples
```

I know I can rename each element individually. But I'd like a way to do this at once for the whole column. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can also split on comma and take the first element using `str.split.str[0]`,

```
df['city'] = df['city'].str.split(',').str[0]
```

Output:

```
             city
0        Rockford
1  St. Petersburg
2   Oklahoma City
3         Memphis
4    Indianapolis
5          Naples
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `str.replace` we can try:

```py
df["city"] = df["city"].str.replace(r',[^,]*$', '')
```